# Is it possible to source multiple external chunk from a file in Knitr/ Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have an R-script file `script.r` as,

```
## ---- Chunk-1 ----------
x <- rnorm(1000)

## ---- Chunk-2 ----------
hist(x)
```

Now in my rmarkdown document `doc.rmd`, I can read the `script.r` file as,

```
knitr::read_chunk("script.r")
```

I can execute both the chunks as follows,

````
```{r Chunk-1}
```

```{r Chunk-2}
```
````

Is there anyway, I can execute `Chunk-1` and `Chunk-2` together. In my real situation, I have lots of chunks, and I want them separate in script file but I need some of them execute together in the `Rmd` file. I am wondering if there is any easier approach rather than repeating blank chunk block.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but I do not see the goal of using your `script.r` file as chunks. When looking at your example, if you want to execute your `script.r` file in your Rmd file, you can directly use `source('script.r')`.

Except if you want to execute some chunks based on conditions for instance. In that aim, do you know that you can call a complete external Rmd file as a child document ?

Your `child-script.Rmd`:

````
```{r Chunk-1}
x <- rnorm(1000)
```

```{r Chunk-2}
hist(x)
```
````

Your main Rmd script:

````
Some markdown text
```{Call_child, child='./child-script.Rmd'}
```
Some other markdown text
````